# php syntax checker and server disagree. Syntax checker is correct?

Tags: php, syntax, casting, logarithm, parse-error

The syntax checker I am referring to is a [neat little tool](http://tools.sopili.net/php-syntax-check/) that I've used to help me check my code before committing it over our tortoiseSVN. It's never lead me astray until today.

I've made a simple function to find the order of magnitude of a number passed in, incomplete but included below:

```
function( $graphMax )
{
$a = (int)log10( $graphMax );
echo "<br><br>GRAPHMAX LOG-10: " . $a . "<br><br>";
$a = pow( 10 , $a );
return $a;
}
```

This will return the lowest value of that order of magnitude( 10,000 for numbers between 10,000-99,999 ).

The issue I am having is this part of the function:

```
$a = (int)log10( $graphMax );
```

The syntax checker says that there are no errors in the syntax when I copy/paste  the entire file into it, but when I submit and run it on our server, I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING in /*/global_functions.php on line 364
```

***as requested, this is the code above the function:***

```
function countSections( $testID )
```

{
    require( 'config.php');

```
//Connect to database server
$dsl_sqlh = mysql_connect( $dsl_db_host, $dsl_db_user , $dsl_db_pass )
      or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db ( $dsl_db , $dsl_sqlh) or die ("Unable to select database");

//Get Section ID.
//With this we can query the correct section 
$secQuery = sprintf("SELECT test_section_name FROM v_ak47_test_section WHERE ak47_testhistory_id= $testID and obsolete = 0");
$secResults = mysql_query($secQuery , $dsl_sqlh);
$rows = mysql_num_rows( $secResults );  

if( $rows > 0 )
{   
    return $rows;
}
else
{
    echo "<br><br>Test has no sections! Check test ID provided.<br><br>";
    return null;
}
```

}

***Answer: I didn't name the function. I have no idea how I missed that. It's early... I need more coffee:( Thanks for the help everyone! Sorry it was so anti-climatic. My last few posts have been like this.***

Comment: Which line in the code is 364

Comment: Can you post the code that comes before this function definition too?

Comment: line 364 is function( $graphMax ), sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your function a name

```
function {ENTER NAME HERE}( $graphMax )
{
   $a = (int)log10( $graphMax );
   echo "<br><br>GRAPHMAX LOG-10: " . $a . "<br><br>";
   $a = pow( 10 , $a );
   return $a;
}
```

Comment: Thats alright it so easy to do when you have been working on something for an amount of time.

Comment: @Joshua Not necessarily. It could be an anonymous function (granted it's not being used as one).

Comment: I meant to name it graphMax, so I call it in another function as such, so it technically did need a name. Working great now!

Learning that anonymous functions is a side benefit I gained from this though; always nice to learn new things:)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is most likely that you are running PHP 5.2 on the server, but have 5.3 checked off when you run the syntax checker (default). Anonymous functions are not allowed in 5.2, but are in 5.3. Check the 5.2 option and run the syntax checker again, you will get the same error you reported.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Your syntax *is* valid 5.3, it's just not doing anything.

When in doubt, trust what the server says :)